# Create new column depending on values from other column with SAS Base in Enterprise Guide

Tags: database, sas, enterprise-guide

I need help with a SAS Base programming. 
How to create a new column (in this case column "BONUS") with values depending on values from another column (column column_one).
Code I've tried:

```
if (t1.column_one=110) or (t1.column_one=111) 
    then put -(t1.BONUS) * 10 * 10;
    else put (t1.BONUS) * 10 * 10;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `put` statement doesn't create a new column. It merely prints text to the log (or any other device you would have specified with the `file` statement).

The 'table[dot]column' notation is used in SQL and does not make sense in that `if` statement which is data step code.

Also, you say you want to create a new column called `BONUS`, yet in your sample code you multiply instead of giving it a value. I will assume the column already exists.

A valid if condition would then be

```
if column_one in (110,111) then BONUS=-BONUS*100;
else BONUS=BONUS*100;
```